# Without maxSDKVersion, my app shows API Level 17-19 in playstore console

Tags: android, gradle

I have uploaded my app to app store with the following gradle file. But my app supports api level 17-19 only. I couldn't find what I have done wrong.
My app gradle file:

```
 android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example"
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 57
        versionName "5.7"
        targetSdkVersion 30
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled true
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
        minSdkVersion 17

    }
    lintOptions {
        disable 'MissingTranslation'
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            firebaseCrashlytics {
                // If you don't need crash reporting for your debug build,
                // you can speed up your build by disabling mapping file uploading.
                mappingFileUploadEnabled false
            }
        }

        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
}
```

Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example”>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    
    <application
        android:name=".activity.BaseApplication"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/app_icon"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:replace="android:allowBackup">

        <activity
            android:name=".activity.LoginMainActivity"
            android:isScrollContainer="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppThemeNoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>
        
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.AccountConfirmation"
            android:isScrollContainer="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppThemeNoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>
        
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.SplashActivity"
            android:isScrollContainer="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppThemeNoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="[API KEY]” />
<meta-data
    android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
    android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

<activity
    android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
    android:label="@string/app_name" />
 <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example”
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Could you show us your compiled/initial `AndroidManifest.xml` file? You might have overridden the SDK version in your manifest file.

Comment: @Edric I have added manifest file.

Comment: Looks like you've added your API key in your code snippet! Please _reset your API key_ as your API key may be used for malicious purposes if you don't secure it.